# How to extract and combine specific data tables in hive database. Found some errors

Tags: database, hive

```
SELECT
ps.hotel_id,
ps.name,
ps.country,
ps.city,
ps.chain_name,
ps.account_manager,
ps.adf_2_0,
t.booker_cc1,
sum(kpi.as_booked_roomnights) as ABRN,
sum(kpi.booked_roomnights) as BRN,
sum(kpi.cancelled_roomnights) as CRN,
sum(kpi.booked_price_euro) as booked_rev,
sum(kpi.stayed_roomnights) as SRN,
sum(kpi.stayed_price_euro) as stayed_rev,
sum(kpi.as_booked_commission_euro) as abc,
FROM reporting.kpi_booked_cancelled_stayed kpi
JOIN reporting.property_splits ps ON kpi.hotel_id=ps.hotel_id
JOIN fpa.transactions_detail t ON ps.hotel_id = t.hotel_id
where 
to_date(kpi.yyyy_mm_dd) BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-05'
AND ps.region ='APAC'
AND ps.is_global_chain ='1'
AND ps.is_open_bookable ='1'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Hi, I wanted to extract some tables from hive and combine them together. However I got some error. Here is what I got:
***error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 17:0 cannot recognize input near 'FROM' 'reporting' '.' in selection target

Answer (score 0):

Extra comma here:

`sum(kpi.as_booked_commission_euro) as abc,`  --remove comma

Comment: Thanks, man. I tried before I asked this question. Yet it did not work.